# Hibernate não reconhece anotação das classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven, glassfish

Tenho um projeto Maven, com Glassfish 4.0, Hibernate, estou utilizando anotações e meu projeto foi facetado com JPA o arquivo persistence.xml foi gerado e a connection pool do Glassfish está funcionado. no entando a seguinte mensagem é gerada pelo inspetor do Eclipse:

***Class "com.financeiro.Pessoa" is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file***

***persistence.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Finaceiro" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MavenDB</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.financeiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>Finaceiro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Dependências do Projeto -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Servlets API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Núcleo do Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Implementação de EntityManager da JPA -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Driver JDBC do MySQL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Como estou utilizando anotações é necessário mapear as classe no persistence.xml ou o erro gerado é por outro motivo ? Gostaria de saber se alguém tem a solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve adicionar a classe `com.financeiro.Pessoa` no seu `persistence.xml`.

Coloque a seguinte linha antes da linha que contém `<properties>`:

```
<class>com.financeiro.Pessoa</class>
```

Uma alternativa, que não é suportada oficialmente pela especificação JPA, mas funciona no Hibernate, é adicionar a seguinte propriedade:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
```

Comment: Perfeito o erro parou de ocorrer no entanto mesmo assim as tabelas do Banco de dados não estão sendo geradas

Comment: A propriedade *exclude-unlisted-classes* é da especificação JPA e faz o serviço.